# nodejs ejs include unexpected identfier

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

i'm using nodejs + express + ejs and i am having a problem when i try to include another view.

When I try:

```
<% include dochead %>
```

I get 'unexpected identifier';
when i try:

```
<% include /admin/global/dochead %>
```

I get 'include is not defined';

What is going on?
Thanks

Comment: thanks for the downvote, whoever you are.

Comment: Getting the same thing. No idea

Comment: @Brig I haven't found any solution, i started using Swig as a templating engine and never looked back

Comment: @user2235057: I switch from ejs to swig. I couldn't waste anymore time fighting a templating engine.

Comment: ok. I have got this to working. I was getting `unexpected identifier` error because I was using an older version of ejs. Switching to its latest version solved issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Try**

```
<%- include ('dochead') %>
```

**or**

```
<%- include ('admin/global/dochead') %>
```

**set**

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'YOUR CUSTOM VIEW FOLDER PATH FROM ROOT FILE');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here `<% include /admin/global/dochead %>` should be

`<% include ../admin/global/dochead %>`

or

`<% include admin/global/dochead %>`

depending on the location.
Also check the view engine you use

`app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`